# Formatted string "spilling" out of column

Tags: c#

I'm brand new to C# and I couldn't figure out what to search for. I'm trying to print a list of strings in a "column" to the right of another list of strings. Two of the strings in the right "column" have multiple values that each need their own line. But when I try to do this, the values that need their own lines just end up all the way over on the left, instead of staying within their "column".

Here's what I want to see:

[image]

And here's what I get:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ut = "1Y, 4D, 01:23:45";
    string met = "T+4D, 01:11:32";
    string vesselName = "Saturn K";
    string vesselModules = "Command/Service Module \nMunar Excursion Module";
    string kerbals = "Valentina Kerman, Pilot; \nJebediah Kerman, Pilot; \nBill Kerman, Engineer; \nBob Kerman, Scientist";

    string[] headerNames = { "UT:", "MET:", "Vessel:", "Modules:", "Crew:" };
    string[] headerData = new string[5] { ut, met, vesselName, vesselModules, kerbals };

    for (int index = 0; index < headerNames.Length; index++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], headerData[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you got several items in one column. It can easily be solved by splitting the items instead of creating new rows. Note that I'm using `;` instead of `\n`.

```
    string ut = "1Y, 4D, 01:23:45";
    string met = "T+4D, 01:11:32";
    string vesselName = "Saturn K";
    string vesselModules = "Command/Service Module;Munar Excursion Module";
    string kerbals = "Valentina Kerman, Pilot;Jebediah Kerman, Pilot;Bill Kerman, Engineer;Bob Kerman, Scientist";

    string[] headerNames = { "UT:", "MET:", "Vessel:", "Modules:", "Crew:" };
    string[] headerData = new string[5] { ut, met, vesselName, vesselModules, kerbals };
    for (int index = 0; index < headerNames.Length; index++)
    {
        // Split data if there are more than one.
        var items = headerData[index].Split(';');
        if (items.Length > 1)
        {
            // We got more than one item. Render first item.
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], items[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i ++)
            {
                // Render the following items.
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", string.Empty, items[i]);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // Only one item. Render it as usual.
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], headerData[index]);
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Edit based on comment:**

`Console.WriteLine` uses the `string.Format()` pattern. From `Console`:

```
// Writes out a formatted string and a new line.  Uses the same 
// semantics as String.Format.
// 
public virtual void WriteLine (String format, params Object[] arg)
{
    WriteLine(String.Format(FormatProvider, format, arg));
}
```

Which basically says that replace every `{}` with the parameter passed. You can view `{}` as a placeholder. I simply said that it should use an empty value.

Examples:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", "One", "Two", "Three");
```

Output:

```
One - Two - Three
```

This is very much like the example in the question, but the question also defines the number of characters that should be displayed, using `{0,-12}`. What I did is to simply pass an empty string, such as "".

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", "One", string.Empty, "Three");
```

Output:

```
One -  - Three
```

And in my code I simply say that the first 12 characters shouldn't be replaced with anything, but still use 12 characters:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", string.Empty, "Some value");
```

You can read more about string.Format here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/format

Regarding incrementation, what I did is to fill an array with your values. And if I detect that it's more than one value I know that the second line (and all the following) should have an "empty header". By passing string.Empty to the Console.WriteLine it will render an empty header (but still a header).

Pseudo code:

```
Split by ';'.
Is there more than one item? If yes, goto 1. If no, goto 2.

1. Render first line with header and first data.
1.1 Render all the other lines, but with an empty header (still taking up 12 chars).

2. Render line with header and data.
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! Quick question: I get the string.Split will split the string using that character as a marker, but I don't really understand what the increment and string.Empty parts do. How does incrementing "i" to the length of "items" put the string after ";" on the next line? I'm trying my best to read the MSDN guide, but I only understand so much of it.

Comment: @blorgon I've made an edit to my answer. I hope it will explain the logic. If not, please ask again.

Comment: Wow! Above and beyond! Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow and the fantastic world of C#. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your `vesselModules` and `kerbals` has `\n` which cause the code to move to new line so after `\n` its starting from column 0. So if you try to remove `\n`it will work fine.

Comment: This will render all vesselModules and all kerbals in the same line, which is not the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can split these strings in arrays and use a nested loop to print these in newlines.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ut = "1Y, 4D, 01:23:45";
    string met = "T+4D, 01:11:32";
    string vesselName = "Saturn K";
    string vesselModules = "Command/Service Module \nMunar Excursion Module";
    string kerbals = "Valentina Kerman, Pilot; \nJebediah Kerman, Pilot; \nBill Kerman, Engineer; \nBob Kerman, Scientist";

    string[] headerNames = { "UT:", "MET:", "Vessel:", "Modules:", "Crew:" };
    string[] headerData = new string[5] { ut, met, vesselName, vesselModules, kerbals };

     for (int index = 0; index < headerNames.Length; index++) {
         if(headerNames[index] == "Modules:" || headerNames[index] == "Crew:") {
            string dataStr = headerData[index];
            var data = dataStr.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], data[0] ?? string.Empty);
            for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", string.Empty, data[i]);
            }
         } else {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], headerData[index]);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like my example. At the top you can define column separator and table width

```
class Program
{
    static int tableWidth = 77;
    static string columnSeparator = string.Empty;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ut = "1Y, 4D, 01:23:45";
        string met = "T+4D, 01:11:32";
        string vesselName = "Saturn K";
        string vesselModules = "Command/Service Module \nMunar Excursion Module";
        string kerbals = "Valentina Kerman, Pilot; \nJebediah Kerman, Pilot; \nBill Kerman, Engineer; \nBob Kerman, Scientist";

        string[] headerNames = { "UT:", "MET:", "Vessel:", "Modules:", "Crew:" };
        string[] headerData = new string[5] { ut, met, vesselName, vesselModules, kerbals };

        for (int index = 0; index < headerNames.Length; index++)
        {
            var multiCol = headerData[index].Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var col in multiCol)
            {
                PrintRow(new string[] { counter == 0 ? headerNames[index] : string.Empty, col });
                counter++;
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void PrintRow(params string[] columns)
    {
        int width = (tableWidth - columns.Length) / columns.Length;
        string row = columnSeparator;

        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            row += AlignLeft(column, width) + columnSeparator;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(row);
    }

    static string AlignCentre(string text, int width)
    {
        text = text.Length > width ? text.Substring(0, width - 3) + "..." : text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return new string(' ', width);
        }
        else
        {
            return text.PadRight(width - (width - text.Length) / 2).PadLeft(width);
        }
    }

    static string AlignLeft(string text, int width)
    {
        text = text.Length > width ? text.Substring(0, width - 3) + "..." : text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return new string(' ', width);
        }
        else
        {
            return text.PadRight(width);
        }
    }
}
```